# Tasks sequence in Prefect Flow Python

Tags: python, data-science, workflow, prefect

I'm currently working with the Python framework - Prefect (prefect.io)
I wrote the code below

```
from prefect import Flow, task
@task
def say_hello():
    print('Hello')

@task
def say_how_a_u():
    print('How are you?')

@task
def say_bye():
    print('Bye Bye')

with Flow('Test') as flow:
   say_hello()
   say_how_a_u()
   say_bye()

flow.run()
```

The fact is that all functions are called in parallel. How to make one function call after another and waited for the previous function? hello -> how_a_u -> bye

I work with triggers, but it fail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just specify the upstream dependencies during the Flow block. There is another syntax you can find [here](https://docs.prefect.io/orchestration/faq/faq.html#how-do-i-set-a-task-to-be-an-upstream-task)

```
from prefect import Flow, task
@task
def say_hello():
    print('Hello')

@task
def say_how_a_u():
    print('How are you?')

@task
def say_bye():
    print('Bye Bye')

with Flow('Test') as flow:
   a = say_hello()
   b = say_how_a_u(upstream_tasks=[a])
   c = say_bye(upstream_tasks=[b])

flow.run()
```